# Using % with numbers in SQL Server Mgmt Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've come across a bit of code that is used to validate a number inputted.

It uses a percentage sign but is nothing to do with any LIKE or varchar functions - it is doing some sort of calculation but I cannot figure it out.

Essentially it looks like this: `1 % 11`

If the second number is bigger than the first it will always bring back the first, but if the second is less than the first it brings back strange results.

Does anyone know what this function is doing?

Answer (score 3):

It is modulo operator (division remainder). See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279(v=sql.120).aspx) for details.